# Searchable Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have dropdownlist filled by database. how can I make it searchable?
I can do it with some issues but when data bind with database in note working.
is my filling method wrong?

```
<asp:Label ID="lbProbType" runat="server" Text="Problem Type"" 
Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>



if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"");
                string readnamesquery = "select cwFullTitle from tbCowWorkers order by cwLName";
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(readnamesquery, cn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
               
                dpCaller.DataSource = dt;
                dpCaller.DataTextField = "cwFullTitle";
                dpCaller.DataBind();
                cn.Close();
            }
```